# Why is roblox creating a leaderstats for me?

Tags: roblox

So, I'm currently working on a roblox game and roblox automatically made a leaderstats for me. I coded my own but it still goes with roblox's leaderstats not mine how can I fix this?

here's the picture of the leaderstats

[image]

Comment: Did you use a template as your starting place?

Answer (score 0):

Roblox doesn't create leaderstats for you, use the search all (<kbd>CTRL/Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) and search for `leaderstats` and see what script created it.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost defently created by a free model or a plugin. Check free models for scripts and look at what your plugins do.

Comment: I'll try to look through the plugins because it can happen even if i create a new game and just join it.

Comment: @MyNameAlan are you using free models in your game?